# How to redirect to desired page in Vue js using vue-router?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

This is my code for `requiresAuth` and `requiresGuest`

`requiresAuth` : Users who satisfy this cannot go to login page or signup page ( meta for `/` )

`requiresGuest` : Users who satisfy this cannot go to `/` or any other page having `requiresAuth` meta for `/login` and `/signup`

These 2 conditions are working perfectly fine for my page

**Problem** :

`Step-1` Lets say i have been given a url like `localhost:8000/api/createapi/.......`

`Step-2` So currently i am not logged in, I enter the above `URL` and it redirects me to the `log in` page (which is expected)

`Step-3` But when i log back in it redirects me to `/` (which is **not ideal** )

**What i want** :

After `Step-2` When i log in it should redirect me automatically to `localhost:8000/api/createapi/.......`
Since that was the requested URL in `Step-1`

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {    
// check for required auth guard
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    requiresAuthLogic(to, next, from)
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresGuest)) {
    requiresGuestLogic(to, next)
  } else {
    // Proceed to route
    next()
  }
})
function requiresAuthLogic (to:Route, next:Function) {
  // check if NOT logged in
  if (!isUserLoggedIn()) {
    // Go to login
    next({
      path: '/login',
      query: {
        redirect: to.fullPath
     }
    })
  } else if (isUserEmailVerified() === true) {
    // Proceed to route
    next()
  }
}

function requiresGuestLogic (to:Route, next:Function) {
  if (isUserLoggedIn() && isUserEmailVerified() === true) {
    next({
      path: '/',
      query: {
        redirect: to.fullPath
      }
    })
  } else {
    // Proceed to route
    next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you need to use the value which is being passed via the redirect parameter

This should be done in your login function if login is successful, you haven't shared your login function but something like this:

```
loginUser() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loginUser', {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    })
        .then(() => {
            this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly and doing this worked like a charm... you saved me alot of time ... i thought there was something wrong with my `router.ts` hence did not post the login method :P

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)